# How to make entities fall through illuminated side of collider?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, physics, game-mechanics

I'm trying to make a prototype, but I'm still new to Unity so not sure what's the best approach to take.

Consider this arena:
[image: 2D game with point light casting shadows from platforms]

Essentially, I want the shadowed parts of the outer rectangles to behave as a normal collider, i.e. if I put a character affected by gravity onto them, they shouldn't pass through. If that character walks onto an illuminated part though, it should behave like the wall has `isTrigger` set to `true` and they should fall through.

How can I achieve this? Currently, each side of the wall is its own GameObject, so I have 4 here in total. I'm relatively sure you can't make part of a collider a trigger, and another part not a trigger, so I've tried to think of some other solutions;

- Make the wall trigger/not trigger based on whether the character is in the shadow or not. I could do this with a raycast check (i.e see if the character, or one of its hitboxes, can see the 'sun'). One issue with this solution though; what if there's multiple entities? Say I had enemies approaching the character; I'd want them to fall/not fall the same way, and I can't set the same wall to be both trigger and not-trigger.
- Something funky with the lighting? I've been using the 2d global lighting so far (it's how I made the screenshot), but from what I can tell there's no way to ask a collider how much light is falling onto it.
- Dynamically re-sizing multiple gameObjects with colliders on them? This to me seems the only viable path, but I don't know how inefficient/silly it is. Essentially, each wall would have to be subdivided into individual objects, one for each section of light and shadow (so in my screenshot, the top wall would just have 1 segment, left wall 2, bottom wall 5, right wall 4). Depending on whether they can see the sun/light, they have `isTrigger` set to true/false. Is this even doable?
- Some other Unity magic!

Comment: Your first approach is similar to how one-way platforms work, turning on and off collision based on the character's position and movement state. Have you considered using `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision` to handle the multiple entities case?

Comment: There is a build in version for the one way platform https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlatformEffector2D.html and playing around with the collision matrix based on light source to player

Comment: If you can get Platform Effector 2D to work, that's a much cleaner suggestion than mine, but as a fallback... You might get more mileage by inverting the problem... Removing parts of colliders in specific areas can be tricky, but adding a few should be simpler... Presumably you only need 2-3 colliders per entity at any one time. Might be easier to instantiate some partial-surface colliders (based on shadow boundaries)  and move them around rather than trying to cut holes in larger colliders

Comment: @Zibelas that seems possible, I've never used collision matrices though, how would I construct one for this case based on the light source/ray casts?

Comment: It is probably even easier to just adjust the value of surface ark/ rotational offset (parameters of the platform effector). If that is enough for your game is hard to say but you could playtest that real fast with a fixed light and your player